# Can you identify this Cateye HR Sensor E product model?

Tags: heart-rate, sensor

I must've bought this like 4-5 years ago. My fat ass never got around to using it. I've since lost the Cateye watch I bought with it.

1. Can anyone identify the model?
2. Do you know if it has a ANT+ sensor?

[image]

There are no model number identifiers on the product. Removing the battery cap reveals nothing. Searches are turning up nothing. I'd like to keep it, buy another ANT+ watch and start working out finally. But don't want to buy NOS gear if it's not within my interest to do so.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It is not ANT+ - only the HR-11 is listed on "thisisant.com" (and its too old to be ANT+)

I suspect it will analogue - most likely would be Polar compatible but cannot be certain. There are Cateye digital monitors, and also ANT+ monitors, the digital ones have "Digital" written on them, which is why I suspect analogue

Best option (IMHO) would be to turf it and go ANT+... The other go down to a local gym, or find a someone with Polar compatible gear and see if their gear picks it up (put in a new battery). But what will you do if you can find this out - buy a new watch based on obsolete technology?

Comment: Thanks! You're right. This is too old to salvage. Maybe I could resell if someone needs a replacement.  I'm thinking I'm going to go ANT+ and use IpBike! I still have a Cateye Strada/Cadence wired computer. But this IpBike on Android is looking sick.

Comment: @TaiSem You do seem to end up with a collection of these things, I have 3 different ones - one to suit my Garmin, one for Polar stuff down at the gym, and a third somewhere that hooks up to the turbo head unit.